# Can two different roles be responsible for the same task in RACI matrix?

Tags: roles, organizational-structure, responsibility

Can two different roles be **responsible** for the same task in the RACI matrix?

If Yes, how do you ensure that there will be no conflict between those two roles when it comes to actual task delivery?

If No, does it mean that the matrix is inadequate when it comes to assigning responsibilities to the appropriate roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an expanded version to RACI called "RASCI" - the "s" stands for "support".

The support takes an active part in working on the task.

> **Responsible**
>
> Those responsible for the task, who ensure that it is done as per the approver
>
> **Support**
>
> Resources allocated to responsible. Unlike consulted, who may provide input to the task, support helps complete the task.

See: https://lifehacker.com/use-the-rasci-matrix-to-manage-responsibility-on-a-proj-1753137259